# Mongodb: update collection imediatly after aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I execute an aggregation that's output is 2 new field.

```
db.Messages.aggregate(
[
    {$match : {
        "Payload": /(([1-2]?[0-9])-([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)-([0-9]*))/}
       },...
{
    $out : "tmp_Messagess"  // create new Collection
}
```

by using  $**out** I have inserted 2 new field into new collection called **tmp_Messagess**. after inserted I have updated old collection with new collection:

```
var bulkOps = db.tmp_Messagess.find().map(function (doc) {
   return {
        "updateOne": {
            "filter": {"_id" : doc._id},
            "update": { "$set": {"BusinessCode" : doc.BusinessCode , "Domain" : doc.Domain}} 
        }
   }
});

db.Messages.bulkWrite(bulkOps, { "ordered": true });
```

updating in this way, it's to long. because I have to run 2 heavy query. first create new collection after aggregation and next, update old collection with documents inside the new collection.

Is there any way that I can directly update main collection inside my aggregate command or I have to use old way that i mention in this post?

Comment: If you are using node, make a callback

Comment: no, I'm not using node.I am running the code inside Robo 3t ide.

Answer (score 0):

I have created two sample collections named test1 and test2 respectively.,

```
//this is my fist collection
db.test1.insert({"fullName": "Srikar Jammi","uname": "srikarjammi"});
db.test1.insert({"fullName": "Viswa Pradeep","uname": "vpradeep"});

//this is my second collection
db.test2.insert({"fullName": "Srikar Jammi","uname": "srikarjammi", 
"age":24, "city": "Hyderabad"});
db.test2.insert({"fullName": "Viswa Pradeep","uname": "vpradeep", 
"age":28, "city": "Guntur"});
```

for now i want to get data from collection(test2: because it has other keys which are not in test1) one by uname(which is a common key in both collections). So, you can do this.,

```
result = db.test2.find({}).map(function(a){return a});
//output
[
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7c072742f432f35421f931"),
    "fullName" : "Srikar Jammi",
    "uname" : "srikarjammi",
    "age" : 24,
    "city" : "Hyderabad"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7c072b42f432f35421f932"),
    "fullName" : "Viswa Pradeep",
    "uname" : "vpradeep",
    "age" : 28,
    "city" : "Guntur"
}
]
```

Now the result holds the data of second collection(test2). then finally i have to update the collection with respective keys(age, city) for this.,

```
finalRes = result.forEach(
function (elem) {
    db.test1.update({
        "uname": elem.uname
    },
    {
            $set: {
                "age": elem.age,
                "city":elem.city
            }
        }
    )
    }
);
```

Finally `(db.test1.find({});`
) by this you find the collection one(test1) with updated keys(age, city)

Correct me if i am wrong or any solutions are much appreciated.
Thanks